# What are requirements of web page must be for sharing link in Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

For example, there is a page with a description, title and image.
Somehow the image is not displayed when I try share link in Facebook.
Possible, the picture should be a specific size or tags? How about meta tags `title`, `desctiption`

Answer (score 0):

The recommended size for images in links is 1200X628.

[Here](http://www.jonloomer.com/2014/01/20/facebook-image-dimensions/) is a reference to all facebook related image dimesnions.

Comment: I checked now, the FB showed me image from CSS style, how is possible?

Comment: the answer is not correct, it is actually 1200x630